# explicitly throw an exception to Spring @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a function for which exception handling and rollback mechanism has been done as shown below.

Can the function throw an exception explicitly(something like throw) when certain condition is satisfied.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
public String addProfileInfo(some args){
   if(some condition){
      //throw error ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it couldn't?

Comment: did you try it ? did give you an error ?

Comment: I have tried `throw new Exception("No public group present");`.This gives a compile time exception _Unhandled exception type Exception_. But if I put add throws to the function the error goes. I have to rollback the transaction if exception occurs in the function. So I need `@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})` to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

First create some custom Exception class:

```
public class SomeRandomException extends Exception {

  public SomeRandomException(String message){
     super(message);
  }

}
```

Then:

```
if(some condition){
    throw new SomeRandomException("This is exception message");
}
```

Ofcourse, replace `SomeRandomException` with whatever you like.....

Example:

```
public class someClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws HueHueException{
        if(someCondition)
            throw new HueHueException("HuiHuiExceptionOccured");
    }

}

class HueHueException extends Exception {

      public SomeRandomException(String message){
         super(message);
      }

}
```